# Marketing Cloud new Transactional API - Error while activating definition

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

My MC account just got enabled on the new transactional email API which was "released" a couple weeks ago. I'm following the documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/createSendDefinition.htm). The POST to create the definition returns returns an error message "MCMS_UTM_Runtime: Error while activating definition", though I can see the definition is created when I issue a subsequent GET to /messaging/v1/email/definitions. When I then try to issue a PATCH to activate the definition ({"status": "Active"} as the PATCH body) I get the same runtime error.

Is this new API ready for primetime? Are there other people using it yet successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I talked to support. It turns out that the content template is validated as part of the email definition creation process. My template was referencing some variables that were not in the data extension that I was trying to use for the send definition.